# Redirect to intranet server at a specific port

Tags: windows, redirect, port, intranet

In my office, I've set up two servers on one Windows 7 machine (and our network is a Windows domain).  One is Apache, running on port 80, and another is the built in trac server running on port 8080.  I've got a DNS entry that redirects reviewboard.etc.etc to the apache server, but for the trac server it still expects the port to be specified.  How can I make it so that trac.etc.etc redirects to machinename:8080?

**Edit**:

The solution, in case someone stumbles upon this later.  The following went inside the `<virtualhost *:80>` block in a file included from my httpd.conf:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^trac\.etc\.etc
RewriteRule (.*) http://localhost:8080$1 [P]
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
```

**Edited again** to include ProxyPassReverse, without which all URLs generated by the proxied server *will break*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what "trac" is but if its default port is 8080 then set a A record for your public IP and do a NAT and Firewall through. In the more likely case its a web app/server then you still set the A record but DNS is not port aware, users will have to enter the 8080 unless you setup a redirect through Apache using something like mod redirect. - Sam's idea

Comment: As he already has Apache handling incoming requests on port 80, I would suggest that he setup forwarding from Apache to TRAC, using mode rewrite or similar.

Comment: True I thought about including that ;edit time.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use mod_proxy to handle the redirection to another server/port seamlessly as a passthrough.  The basic documentation for mod_proxy available on apache.org covers how to do this.